# How can i keep a ball from sticking to an object that isn't there

Tags: python, keydown

I am in school taking my first Programming course, Python.  I am on Windows 7, python 3.4.3. My project is a Pong based game.  The paddle is a rectangle, Ball is a circle.  I got the ball to bounce around and off the paddle.  MY game contains the ability to have the ball stick to the paddle when the SPACE BAR is held and you can move the ball & paddle with the UP Down arrow keys. This works!  However, if I hold the space bar down and the ball is nowhere near the paddle, the ball sticks in place at the X position of the paddle as if it stuck to a paddle that isn’t there.  I tried adding print statements in the code with no help.  I searched the web but nothing comes close to my problem.  My instructor was stumped and suggested you guys for your Fast, Excellent service.  Hope he’s right!!    If you can point out any other mistakes, that would be greatly appreciated     Here is my code:

```
# Pong game
# By Bill B
# Fall 2015
#
# My first post had an issue.  This should work
# Sorry this is my first posting...  AAAaaa...  2nd now

import pygame, time
pygame.init()

# Define Colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red   = (255, 0, 0)
blue  = (0, 0, 255)
blue4 = (170, 170, 220)

boardWid  = 800       # Game Board width 
boardHgt  = 600       # Game board height
pHgt      = 100       # Paddle height
pWith     = 10        # Paddle Width

font  = pygame.font.SysFont(None,48)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((boardWid,boardHgt))
#print(gameDisplay)
pygame.display.set_caption("Kong Pong")

#====================================================
def msgToScreen( msg, color ):
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [boardWid/4,boardHgt/2])
    pygame.display.update()
    #time.sleep(3)

#====================================================
def scoreScreen( score, balls, color ):
    # Display the Balls Left and the Score
    msg = "Balls Left " + str(balls) + "     Score " + str(score)
    screen_text = font.render(msg, True, color)
    gameDisplay.blit(screen_text, [boardWid/4,10])

#====================================================
def showCongrats():
    # Displat the Congratulations/Next Level screen
    gameDisplay.fill(blue4)
    msgToScreen("Congratulations... ",red)
    time.sleep(2)
    gameDisplay.fill(blue4)
    msgToScreen("You go to the next level",red)
    time.sleep(3)
#====================================================
def gameLoop(lev, score):  # passing the game level
    balls     = 3   # number of balls allowed
    ball      = 0   # the current ball being played
    hits      = 0   # how many times ball hits paddle
    maxHits   = 5  # how many times ball hits paddle

    for ball in range(1,balls+1):

       FPS       = 60            # set Frames Per Seconds
       gameExit  = False         # Exit Game flag
       spaceKey  = False         # space bar flag
       countSpKy = 0             # Counts the iterations while spaceKey is true
       speed     = 5             # Speed of Ball and Paddle times the level
       padX      = boardWid - 20 # Paddle upper lft corner start X position
       padY      = 300           # Paddle upper lft corner start Y position
       padY_new  = 0             # New Paddle Y position movement variable
       pY        = 0             # Where Ball Hits paddle to position ball at that spot
       ballX     = 400           # Ball upper lft corner start X position
       ballY     = 300           # Ball upper lft corner start X position
       ballX_new = speed         # New Ball X position movement variable
       ballR     = 10            # Ball Radius 
       ballY_new = 0             # New Ball Y position movement variable
       clock = pygame.time.Clock()

       gameExit  = False
       while not gameExit:
           print("\tInside the While   Ball = ",ball)
           for event in pygame.event.get():
               print("\t\tInside the For Event   Ball = ",ball)
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                   gameExit = True
               if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                   if event.key == pygame.K_UP:    # If up arrow paddle goes up
                       padY_new = -speed
                   if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:  # If down arrow paddle goes down
                       padY_new = speed

                   if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                       ballX += ballX_new         # repositions Ball X position
                       ballY += ballY_new         # repositions Ball Y position
                       spaceKey  = True
               if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:  # check up/down arrow keys and space bar
                   if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                       padY_new = 0               # if no arrow key, stop paddle
                   if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                       spaceKey  = False          # reset use of space bar flag
           # Check ball bounderies
           if ballX < 0:               # if ball hits left wall
               ballX_new = speed
               countSpKy = 0              # reinitialize the spaceKey count
               pY = 0                     # reinitialize the Ball/Paddle spacer
           elif ballX >= boardWid:
               gameExit = True
           elif ballY < 0:             # if ball hits floor
               ballY_new = speed
           elif ballY >= boardHgt:     # if ball hits cieling
               ballY_new = -speed
           # Check for space key down
           if not spaceKey:            # If NOT down
               padY  += padY_new          # repositions paddle
               ballX += ballX_new         # repositions Ball X position
               ballY += ballY_new         # repositions Ball Y position
           else:                       # If space bar down
               #  while spaceKey is down and ball is on the paddle make
               #  ball stick to the paddle
               if (ballX > padX - 2 and ballX < padX + pWith ) or \
                  (ballX + ballR > padX -2 and ballX + ballR < padX + pWith):
                   if (ballY > padY and ballY < padY + pHgt) or \
                      (ballY + ballR > padY and ballY + ballR < padY + pHgt):
                       if countSpKy == 0:
                           pY = ballY - padY  # place where the ball hits the paddle
                           score += 5         # add to score
                           hits  += 1         # add to hits
                           if hits == maxHits:
                               showCongrats()
                               return score
                       #else:
                       #    pY = 0
                       countSpKy += 1
                       print("pY = ", pY)
                       print("padY =",padY)
                       print("ballY = ",ballY)
                       ballX = padX -5        # repositions Ball X position
                       ballY = padY + pY      # repositions Ball Y position to the paddle
               else: 
                   ballX += ballX_new         # repositions Ball X position
                   ballY += ballY_new         # repositions Ball Y position
               padY  += padY_new          # repositions paddle     

           # draw object on screen [start, location, ]
           gameDisplay.fill(blue4)
           pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, red, [padX,padY, pWith, pHgt])
           pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, black, [ballX, ballY], ballR)
           scoreScreen( score, balls, blue )
           pygame.display.update()
           # IF the ball hits the paddle add to score
           if (ballX > padX and ballX < padX + pWith) or (ballX + ballR > padX and ballX + ballR < padX + pWith):
               if (ballY > padY and ballY < padY + pHgt) or (ballY + ballR > padY and ballY + ballR < padY + pHgt):
                  if ballY_new == 0:
                     ballY_new = -speed -2
                  ballX_new = -speed
                  if not spaceKey:
                      score += 5
                      hits  += 1
                      if hits == maxHits:  # When you reach the end of a level
                          showCongrats()
                          return score
        #    check the boundries of the paddle
           if padY <= 0:                # if top of paddle hits top of screen
               padY = 0                 # stop the paddle
           if padY + pHgt >= boardHgt:  # if bottom of paddle hits bottom of screen
               padY = boardHgt - pHgt   # stop the paddle
           clock.tick(FPS+ (25 * lev))        # Set frames per second



       msgToScreen("S O R R Y... You Lose a Ball",red)
       balls -= 1
       pygame.display.update()
       time.sleep(3)

    return score
    #  END OF GAMELOOP()

#====================================================
#================  Main Program  ====================

score     = 0   # keepa the score

for lev in [ 1, 2 ]:
    score = gameLoop(lev, score)

gameDisplay.fill(blue4)
msgToScreen("S O R R Y... Game Over",red)
#balls -= 1
time.sleep(3)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Why did you delete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850889/how-can-i-keep-a-ball-from-sticking-to-an-object-that-isnt-there and create a new question?

Comment: The code didn't work.  Had two people tell me so and when I copied and pasted into IDLE, it didn't work for me either.  So I deleted it and created another question with working code.  This is the 1st time using StackOverFlow and didn't know what else to do.  You gotta better way, I'd love to know.

Comment: Generally the edit link, located next to the delete link.

Comment: go figure....  What I'd really like is a solution to my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code with three different systems:

1. MacosX Python 2.6
2. Win32 Python 2.7
3. Win32 Python 3.4

In everyone of them, I can't replicate the problem you mention.
If I press the spacebar when the ball is sufficently far from the paddle (100 px or so) the ball keeps on running and doesn't stop.

I suppose you could have some problem in your system (I don't knwo which one).
I suggest you to try your code in another pc.

EDIT:

The problem is that you forgot to handle one condition. In other words, you forgot an ***else***.
I put the correction in your code below, but be aware: don't copy and paste the code, because indentation could be wrong by one space. Just write the three lines with upperace comment in your code, and it will work:

```
       else:   
           if (ballX > padX - 2 and ballX < padX + pWith ) or \
              (ballX + ballR > padX -2 and ballX + ballR < padX + pWith):
               if (ballY > padY and ballY < padY + pHgt) or \
                  (ballY + ballR > padY and ballY + ballR < padY + pHgt):
                   if countSpKy == 0:
                       pY = ballY - padY 
                       score += 5       
                       hits  += 1      
                       if hits == maxHits:
                           showCongrats()
                           return score
                   #else:
                   #    pY = 0
                   countSpKy += 1
                   print("pY = ", pY)
                   print("padY =",padY)
                   print("ballY = ",ballY)
                   ballX = padX -5      
                   ballY = padY + pY      
               else: # THE CONDITION WERE THE Y WERE NOT TEH SAME AS THE PADDLE WAS NOT HANDLED
                   ballX += ballX_new         # THEREFORE IT JUST CHECKED
                   ballY += ballY_new         # THE X COORDINATE
           else: 
               ballX += ballX_new        
               ballY += ballY_new        
           padY  += padY_new
```

Comment: Sorry...  On the road with little access to internet.  I did Try the code on different PCs....  Several....  Including a couple at school.  Did you try holding the Space Bar down BEFORE the ball gets to  plane of the paddle?  That's what I do.  By the way....   Thanks for taking the time to look at my code.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the problem. The ball freezes when you press spacebar but ONLY when it is on the same x of the pad. Once a collegue of mine realized when the problem occour, he was quickly able to correct the problem.
I edited my answer. you can find the solution there.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST.....  I made the correction and it does indeed work now.  Thanks for your help and thank your colleague for me.  Looks like my instructor was right...  You Guys and Gals are GOOD.  If You folks ever come to Atlanta...  Drinks are on me...  Your choice of beverage.

Comment: Glad it helped :)
Next time I will cross the Atlantic a beer wouldn't be a bad idea ;)
In the meantime, please accept my answer (is the checkmark on the side of my first answer)!